# `this` not properly bound

Tags: javascript

```
deleteSong.onclick = (this)=>{ this.removeWidget(this) }
```

What i want here is the "this" param in `removeWidget(this)` to be binded to the HTMLElement "this" not my class "this"

Class:

```
class Collection{

createElements(){
    let deleteSong = document.createElement('button');
    deleteSong.className += 'delete-song';
    deleteSong.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    deleteSong.onclick = (this)=>{ this.removeWidget(this) }
    deleteSong.innerHTML = '&#10005;';
 }
}
```

For more clarity i'm trying to achieve something like

`<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me</button>`.
Where the 'this' will return the HTMLElement object

Comment: Please give us the html too. All the many `this`s in your question is confusing! I don't see a class .

Comment: `this` in your function parameter is probably the event object, Try `deleteSong.onclick = (event) => { this.removeWidget(event.target) }`. But this is just a guess. We need more context as just stated before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're putting `this` inside your function argument and therefore redefining `this`. Just change it to something else so that when you actually mean `this`, it's `this`.

The `onclick` event will already pass you the `event` in the callback. To access the actual element, you want to use `event.target`

Example:

```js
class Collection {

  createElements() {
    let deleteSong = document.createElement('button');
    deleteSong.className += 'delete-song';
    deleteSong.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    deleteSong.onclick = (e) => { // <- dont use 'this' here.
      this.removeWidget(e.target) // e.target is the html element
    }
    deleteSong.innerHTML = '&#10005;';
    document.getElementById('container').append(deleteSong); // append element
  }
  removeWidget(el) {
    console.log(el);
  }
}

const c = new Collection();
c.createElements();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass **event** as parameter instead of **this** keyword. Something like this would yield you the required element.

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</button>
```

**JS/TS File**

```
deleteSong.onclick = (event)=>{ this.removeWidget(event.target) }
```